Interesting Generalization of Frobenius's Theorem: $k$ divides $| G[k] \cap hG[k] |, \forall h \in G[k]$

Initial Statement:  Let $H=G[2]=\{g\in G:g^2=1\}$.Prove that, for every G satisfying $2\bigm||G|$, the condition $2\bigm||H\cap hH|$ holds for every $h \in H$.

Below I will denote $G[2]$ by $H$.
The proof is easy: When $H \cap hH$ is nonempty, $H \cap hH = hH \cap h^2H=h(H \cap hH)$ because we have $h^2=1$, then we have defined a left translation action on the $
\langle h \rangle$-set $H \cap hH$. Assume $h \neq 1$, otherwise this is an easy exercise almost included in every textbook. (That is, $G[2]$ is even.) Now $h$ becomes a involution (element of order 2), and since every orbit of the action have the same length 2 (easy exercise), we have $|H \cap hH|$ is an even number.
For example, let $G=S_3$, then $H=G[2]=\{ (1), (12),(23),(13)\}$, and $H \cap (12)H=\{(12),(1)\}$.
It is noteworthy that $h$ cannot just be an element in $G$. For example, $H \cap (123)H=\{(12),(23),(13)\}$ while $(123)$ not in $H$.

Generalizations:
I was inspired by a corollary from Frobenius's theorem,

Corollary: If $G$ is a finite group such that $k \bigm ||G|$ where $k$ is a positive integer, then $ k \bigm | |G[k]| $, where $G[k]:=\{g\in G:g^k=1\}$.

That is to say, we have $k \bigm |H$.
It gives a light to generalize the statement to all positive integer $k$:

Statement:  Let $H=G[k]=\{g\in G:g^k=1\}$.Prove that, for every G satisfying $k\bigm||G|$, the condition $k\bigm||H\cap hH|$ holds for every $h \in H$.

(I should clarify that $H$ will change under the changes of $k$, even if $G$ is fixed.)
For $k=1$ the statement is obviously correct.
Unfortunately, this statement is false, and I will show an example below. At the same time, the method for $k=2$ doesn't seem to work on $k \geq 3$ because we may not be able to define an action on $H \cap hH$. Take $k=6, g=(123), G=S_6$ to see this.
If we take $k=6$, $G=S_6$, $h=(12)(34)$, then $|H \cap hH|=268$, according to calculation by GAP. However $6 \nmid 268$, so the statement is false for $k=6$.

Generalized Problem:  Let $H=G[k]=\{g\in G:g^k=1\}$. Find all such k that, for every G satisfying $k\bigm||G|$, the condition $k\bigm||H\cap hH|$ holds for every $h \in H$.

By checking some small k's and SmallGroups with GAP, I conjecture that the for $1$, $p$ and $p^2$ the statement holds, where $p$ is a prime.

Current Thoughts:
My friend gave me a type of counterexamples for some $k$. He supposed if $k$ doesn't fit the conditions, then a choice of $G$ could be like $$ S_p \wr C_q,$$ where $p$ and $q$ are unknown integers. We have no mind of the choice of $p,q,g$ though. (All wreath products are regular.)
$G=S_3 \wr C_2$ ends the discussion of $k=8$. So not all prime powers are right.
Here is a table on validity of some $k$:



k
validity
counterexample




4




6
×
$S_6$ or $S_4\wr C_2$


8
×
$S_3\wr C_2$


9




10
×
$S_5\wr C_2$


12
×
$S_6\wr C_2$


14
×
$S_7\wr C_2$


15
×
$S_5\wr C_3$


16




18
×
$S_4\wr C_3$


20
×
$S_5\wr C_3$



(@Diamond_153 has solved the case where $k$ is a prime, so I deleted some rows.)

Any help is appreciated.

What is the statement you are looking for? That $2 \mid |H \cap hH|$ for all $h \in H$? Or that $k \mid |H \cap hH|$ for all $h \in H$? Both are false e.g. with $G = S_4$, $k = 6$.

@testaccount As I mentioned in the title, I want to find $k$'s such that $k \bigm | |H \cap hH|$ for all $h \in H$. For $k=2$ the question becomes $2 \bigm | |H \cap hH|$ for groups of even order, which is true. However, for $k=6$, by the example you gave, it is truly false. I'm now trying to prove the statement false for $k$'s that have more than one prime factor.

@testaccount when $k=2$, $H$ stands for $G[2]$ but not $G[6]$.
